# Credentials popup when debugging in VS 2017 IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, authentication, debugging, iis

I have an VS (2017) Web Application project. The project complies and runs correctly etc.

The problem I have is when I press the debug button and it starts debugging using IIS Express in Edge, I am always presented with a popup to provide credentials before the page is shown. The page is loaded correctly once the credentials are provided, but I have to do it each time and it can become annoying.

Anonymous access is disabled and Windows Authentication is enabled in the Project Properties.
I a have tried running VS in adminstrator mode but no luck.

How do I not have the credentials box appear?

Comment: Prompt is rather normal for browsers, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/troubleshoot/browsers/prompt-for-username-and-password So you need to study their settings to suppress that.

Comment: try to use FDN while debugging in visual studio. refer this link for more detail: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/75716/debugging-with-microsoft-edge-prompts-for-credenti.html

Comment: The link on that page has been removed and it doesn't explain how it's done.

Comment: @user1431743 is your issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

set the hostname which you are using in the iis site binding to the visual studio project.

1)Open the project which you are using to attach the worker process for debugging.

2)Right-click on the project -> select properties

you will see that there are 3 options for executing your application. IIS Express, Local IIS or External Host.

You can now use Local IIS like the configuration below.

[image]

A second option, that is if you are using like me a custom hostname, is to select External Host.

[image]